# Merge rows from two arrays which have different depths, but same count

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, mapping

I need to merge two arrays with different depths, but with the same count.  How can I distribute all of the rows from my first array to be the first row in each group of my second array?

```
$array1 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3]
];

$array2 = [
    [
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16]
    ],
    [
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16]
    ],
    [
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16]
    ]
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16]
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16]
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Did you look at [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla yes, dones't work

Comment: did you look at array_merge?

Comment: `array_merge` should do the job : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: @whoami  yes of corse but all tht do is i become from 3 array 6 array it just add first array to second and tht it was but i need to add an array to an subbaray.

Comment: Use a combination of them! `array_map` with `array_merge` on its results.

*Edit* Oops race condition. Eddie's answer below seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla how can i do it without array_map ?

Comment: [Implementation of the advice in the dupe target](https://3v4l.org/oSK94)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map` to loop thru your array and use `array_merge` to merge the 2 arrays.

```
$arary1 = ...

$array2 = ...

$newarray = array_map(function ($a, $b) {
    return array_merge(array($a),$b);
}, $arary1, $array2 );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $newarray );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                    [3] => 7
                    [4] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 11
                    [3] => 12
                    [4] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 16
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                    [3] => 7
                    [4] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 11
                    [3] => 12
                    [4] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 16
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                    [3] => 7
                    [4] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 11
                    [3] => 12
                    [4] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 16
                )

        )

)
```

Or using `foreach` loop

```
$newarray = array();
foreach( $arary1 as $key => $val ) {
    $newarray[] = array_merge(array($val),$array2[$key]);
}
```

Doc: [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: thx of lot, but how can i do this without using array_map ? Maybe an foreach and for ?

Comment: @Eddie, when we have to array_map in arrays

Comment: @CananauCristian I added a sample for foreach